# Get count of several times slots on between given two mysql time slots within datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have several in data and out date mysql `datetime` values. I need to return total count from given `dateperiod` and given time slot

Ex.

```
time               
2012-02-01 10:00
2012-02-01 12:00
2012-02-01 14:00
2012-02-02 09:00       

2012-02-02 10:00       
2012-02-03 11:00
```

how to get data basis on time and date slot form datetime field as in this question i only want to get data from date 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-02 and time from 09:00 to 12:00 hence this should not provide the data of 2012-02-01 14:00 hope you got this now

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code. "Write my code for me" type questions are frowned upon here at SO.

Comment: I just tried between date query but its not fulfilling the time slot condition

Comment: What code did you use to try that? Post it up here.

Comment: Include that SQL statement in your question then, please.

Comment: query I tried  SELECT *  FROM users WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2012-02-01 09:00' AND  '2012-02-02 02:00'

Comment: but its giving me data of this 2012-02-01 14:00 field also I want to get data  within timeslot between two dates

Comment: four is actually correct

Comment: how to get data basis on time and date slot form datetime field as in this question i only want to get data from date 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-02 and time from 09:00 to 12:00 hence this should not provide the data of 2012-02-01 14:00 hope you got this now

Comment: Ok, now I think we understand. Then you need to do something similar to this (syntax is probably wrong, but you get the idea): SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at (BETWEEN '2012-02-01 00:00' AND '2012-02-02 23:59') AND HOUR(created_at ) >= 9 AND HOUR(created_at ) <=12

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT count(*) as c FROM users WHERE created_at 
BETWEEN '2012-02-01 09:00' AND '2012-02-02 02:00' AND 
Time(c) BETWEEN '09:00' AND '02:00'
```

Comment: I don't want to get data only from two dates but this should fulfil the time slot condition also read question carefully please

Comment: how to get data basis on time and date slot form datetime field as in this question i only want to get data from date 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-02 and time from 09:00 to 12:00 hence this should not provide the data of 2012-02-01 14:00 hope you got this now

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your query.  The closing time is 14:00, not 12:00:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2012-02-01 09:00' AND '2012-02-02 14:00' ;
```

EDIT:

If you are trying to limit the times and dates separately, then use two conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE created_at >= '2012-02-01' AND created_at < '2012-02-03'  AND
      time(created_at) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '14:00:00' ;
```

Comment: how to get data basis on time and date slot form datetime field as in this question i only want to get data from date 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-02 and time from 09:00 to 12:00 hence this should not provide the data of 2012-02-01 14:00 hope you got this now

Answer (score 0):

you need only to add count(*) in your statement.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2012-02-01 09:00' AND '2012-02-02 12:00'
```

Comment: how to get data basis on time and date slot form datetime field as in this question i only want to get data from date 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-02 and time from 09:00 to 12:00 hence this should not provide the data of 2012-02-01 14:00 hope you got this now

Comment: how to get data basis on time and date slot form datetime field as in this question i only want to get data from date 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-02 and time from 09:00 to 12:00 hence this should not provide the data of 2012-02-01 14:00 hope you got this now

Answer (score 0):

`2012-02-01 14:00` is rightfully included in the result of your query, what you want to achieve can be done this way

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
(DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-02')
AND
(TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '09:00' AND '12:00')
```

Comment: I have figured out this by myself query is as SELECT * from booking where ( date(created_at) BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-02') AND 
(time(created_at) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '12:00:00') Thanks for all your answers